# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Serve Static Files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to Elastic Beanstalk, trying to serve a Node.js Express app and utilize serving our static files separately with Nginx. None of the tutorials I've come across are explicit in how to define the virtual path.

I'm attempting to do this through the AWS console in the browser. I am trying to add a virtual path/directory setup for the static files. In the console I'm at
`Elastic Beanstalk > myapp > configuration > Static Files`

[image: Elastic Beanstalk console]

But no matter what I add here I get this error message:
[image]

I've also tried adding the full directory path (`/var/app/current/dist/public/images/`). Is there another `.ebextensions/*.conf` file I need to add? I don't have a lot of experience with Nginx so if the fix is a `.conf` file I wouldn't know what it is

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a known bug, They only support python when it comes to the web console. if your application is in nodejs you would need to set these properties from the cli.

you can setup the values from cli this way

```sh
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-id your_enviornment_id --option-settings 'Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles,OptionName=/assets,Value=/static/assets'
```

or editing the config file from `eb config`.

Comment: Wow... I wasted at least a couple hours scratching my head over this. Thank you for your response. It did the trick

Comment: Is there anyway to pass `/` for `OptionName` so that the root serves a static site, or should that be done via nginx redirect in an ebextensions file?

Comment: I want to know the answer to @Jermy 's question as well.

Comment: Note that the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles` setting is for Amazon AMI, which predates Amazon Linux 2. If running the latter, the setting is `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles`. See [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentproxystaticfiles) for the latest info.

Answer (score 3):

Kashif Zaidi's answer works well, but if you want to keep the setting consistent across multiple deployments, you can make a `.ebextensions` directory at the project root with some file like `01_environment_settings.config` that specifies that setting like so:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
    "/assets": "/static/assets"
```

You can specify multiple static file settings, for example:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
    "/app/": "frontend_build/"
    "/static/": "frontend_build/static/"
    "/backend_static": "static/"
```

Comment: What if I wanted to link to s3? like serve images stored in s3 through eb through a subdomain