# elasticbeanstalk won't set virtual paths

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying the new AWS Elastic Beanstalk console ui. I am having a problem now to set up **virtual paths** on ui.

Basically I put all my static files, including index.html in a folder `ui` inside my bundle.

This is the bundle structure:

```
/ui
/ui/favicon.ico
/ui/index.html
/ui/static
/ui/static/css/...
/ui/static/js/...
/ui/static/media/...
package.json
yarn.lock
app.js // this is the node api and it works
```

The API works when access my [http://public]/api/alive. My intention is set virtual directories to serve static files from bundle folder ui.

The node api sends down the `index.html` when it doesn't match anything. This works: [http://public]/. I get the `index.html`.

Then the browser requests static files `/static/js/main[hash].js`. This works but the problem is I can't even set up any virtual path to play around. I need to map the browser request `/static` to `/ui/static` at AWS.

elasticbeanstalk error:

[image]

/static/: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: '/static/'): Unknown configuration setting.
static/: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: 'static/'): Unknown configuration setting.
/assets: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: '/assets'): Unknown configuration setting.
static: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: 'static'): Unknown configuration setting.

No matter where I put the slashes, it wont work:

[image]

All the paths I specified exist inside my deployed app bundle, apart from `/static/assets` which is just to try anything different.

I am not sure if this is a bug on the new UI or not. If anyone had the same problem please let me know.

Comment: Never mind. I'll deploy the web static files to a S3 in a separate step. The downside is I have to make cross-domain API calls to the API. It might be a better structure moving forward.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem described here, and I'm still interested in an answer if anyone has one.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646783/elastic-beanstalk-nginx-serve-static-files

Comment: I found an answer about that same issue for my Node.js EBS there https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655177/1345244

Answer (score 8):

I found this question while trying to serve static content from a **Python 3.7** Django application using **Amazon Linux 2**; however, I think the answer will be the same for different platforms.

Reading the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html) I found this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html

which indicated a `.config` sample file like this

**Example `.ebextensions/static-files.config`**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml  <-- path/to/your/static/dir/ (added by Nick)
    /images: staticimages
```

so, it looks like the namespace changed from `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles` to `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles`. This seems to be a more generic reverse proxy to be platform agnostic which makes sense. Good job AWS.

When I tried this, *amazingly* the documentation was up to date and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Nick's answer- the `/html` or `/images` here will correspond to the path where your environment expects to receive the files.

So if you open up the network tab of your browser console and see something like:
`404 GET http://your.app.com/static/admin/css/base.css`

Then you probably want the path to be `/static` instead of `/html`

The value `statichtml` will correspond to the location of the static files on your eb instance.

So, if you run `eb ssh` and then `manage.py collectstatic` and get an output like this:

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /var/app/current/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

Then you probably want the value to be `/static/`

Answer (score 0):

Creating an ebextensions with this in it worked for me:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```