# How to serve static files from a docker container on Elastic Beanstalk (flask + react build files)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single container docker that consists of my flask-based api and a built react application.

**How do I make Beanstalk run my flask app and serve my static react app files through nginx?**

I have found various potential solutions, but being completely new to Beanstalk it is difficult for me to understand the implications I choose a path to proceed.

1. *.ebextensions*

I assume I can completely rewrite nginx config, but it seems excessive if all I want is to serve some static files?

*2. Copy files to nginx folder.*

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html) page describes how to configure a custom docker container and in what nginx folder files should go

*3. Tell EB to serve static files through UI or CLI*

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646783/elastic-beanstalk-nginx-serve-static-files) discussion covers it. It feels "wrong" going outside docker for getting this to work.

Comment: Can you serve the files using a public S3 bucket?  If you're already on AWS and the content is in fact public this is probably the easiest path.

Comment: Hm I can leverage S3 bucket, but that would mean uploading something there from the docker container. 
What would the solution would look like in this case? Official docs don't seem to mention a solution like that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html

Comment: During your build process, upload things to S3 directly.  Don't run a server to serve them, just use the S3 externally visible URLs.  There's no Docker involved in this path at all.

Comment: for posterity -- aws s3 sync build/ s3://example-bucket --acl public-read